# Reading a Hashmap on a Parcelable Constructor from a Data class in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, android-recyclerview, constructor, parcelable

i'm currently building an app in kotlin, i'm trying to get the data from a single item on a recyclerview to later show it on a details screen, in order to do this im using a parcelable data class, and i'm getting the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.firebasecrudapplication, PID: 21852
    kotlin.NotImplementedError: An operation is not implemented: alumnos
        at com.example.firebasecrudapplication.models.Proyecto.<init>(Proyecto.kt:33)
        at com.example.firebasecrudapplication.models.Proyecto$CREATOR.createFromParcel(Proyecto.kt:84)
        at com.example.firebasecrudapplication.models.Proyecto$CREATOR.createFromParcel(Proyecto.kt:82)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:3333)
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:3226)
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3623)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:292)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:236)
        at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:1002)
        at android.content.Intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.java:8548)
        at com.example.firebasecrudapplication.DetallesProfesorActivity.onCreate(DetallesProfesorActivity.kt:13)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8054)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8034)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1341)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3666)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3842)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2252)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 21852 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:34009', transport: 'socket'
```

It points to the parcel constructor on the Data class, and it shows that two of the fields are not being implemented since they are of the Map data type. This is the data class:

```
data class Proyecto(
    val alcances :String ?= null,
    val alumnos :Map<String, Any>?= null,
    val areasConoc :String?= null,
    val asignaturas :String?= null,
    val cliente :String?= null,
    val colaboradores :String?= null,
    val compDes :String?= null,
    val compPrev :String?= null,
    val coordinador: String?= null,
    val departamentos  :String?= null,
    val impacto :String?= null,
    val institucion :String?= null,
    val justificacion :String?= null,
    val limityrest :String?= null,
    val materiaEje :String?= null,
    val periodo : Map<String, Any> ?= null,
    val plan :String?= null,
    val planteamiento :String ?= null,
    val profeResp :String?= null,
    val tipoejec :String?= null,
    val tituloproyecto :String ?= null

) : Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.readString(),
        TODO("alumnos"),
        parcel.readString()!!,
        parcel.readString()!!,
        parcel.readString()!!,
        parcel.readString()!!,
        parcel.readString()!!,
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        TODO("periodo"),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString()
    ) {
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeString(alcances)
        parcel.writeString(areasConoc)
        parcel.writeString(asignaturas)
        parcel.writeString(cliente)
        parcel.writeString(colaboradores)
        parcel.writeString(compDes)
        parcel.writeString(compPrev)
        parcel.writeString(coordinador)
        parcel.writeString(departamentos)
        parcel.writeString(impacto)
        parcel.writeString(institucion)
        parcel.writeString(justificacion)
        parcel.writeString(limityrest)
        parcel.writeString(materiaEje)
        parcel.writeString(plan)
        parcel.writeString(planteamiento)
        parcel.writeString(profeResp)
        parcel.writeString(tipoejec)
        parcel.writeString(tituloproyecto)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<Proyecto> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Proyecto {
            return Proyecto(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Proyecto?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

Ive tried to make this change: `parcel.readMap<String, Any>()`,  on the fields that ask for a HashMap type but i get the following error:

Type mismatch.
Required:
Map<String, Any>?
Found:
Unit

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to use the [@Parcelize](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/parcelize) annotation to avoid all the boilerplate.  If you have fields you'd like to ignore look into the [transient](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-transient/) keyword.

On a secondary note, `Parcelable`s should only contain other serializable/supported types (if you do decided to try to implement `parcel.readMap()`).  Your Map is mapping to an `Any` type, which is not a `Serializable`, `Parcelable`, or primitive type, which is likely causing the error.